# What does PROXIED attributeDescription "DC" mean?

Tags: openldap

When I type the "slapcat -n 0 -l config"command, the server reports PROXIED attributeDestription "DC" inserted.

What causes this output.
Is there any error in the openldap configuration that I need to fix？Or just ignore this output?